# Change size (height) of ProgressView in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, uiprogressview

I created a `ProgressView` in SwiftUI (using Xcode) and edited a bit but haven’t figured out how to change its height.

```
struct ProgressBar: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ProgressView("Progres:", value: 50, total: 100)
        }.foregroundColor(Color(UIColor.systemBlue))
        .scaleEffect(1, anchor: .center)
        .accentColor(Color(UIColor.systemGreen))
    }
}
```

Comment: Try the `.scaleEffect` modifier as answered [here](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/652733)

Comment: I tried that but that changed the whole ProgressView, not just the linear line as I want.

Comment: Ah I didn't read over the entire image.

Comment: Must see this https://serialcoder.dev/text-tutorials/swiftui/progressview-in-swiftui/

Answer (score 40, accepted):

There's no direct way that I know of to change the height, but you can use the `.scaleEffect` modifier. Make sure to specify `1` for the x scale in order to only increase the height.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ProgressBar()
        .padding([.leading, .trailing], 10)
    }
}

struct ProgressBar: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ProgressView(value: 50, total: 100)
            .accentColor(Color.green)
            .scaleEffect(x: 1, y: 4, anchor: .center)
        }
    }
}
```

Result:
[image: Progress bar with larger height]

A drawback to this is that you can't pass in a Label, because it will also get stretched.

```
ProgressView("Progress:", value: 50, total: 100)
```

[image: The label "Progress:" stretched vertically]

To work around this, just make your own `Text` above the `ProgressView`.

```
struct ProgressBar: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text("Progress:")
            .foregroundColor(Color.blue)
            
            ProgressView(value: 50, total: 100)
            .accentColor(Color.green)
            .scaleEffect(x: 1, y: 4, anchor: .center)
        }
    }
}
```

[image: "Progress:" is not stretched]

Comment: It works but Can you create Rounded Corners in that ProgressView? How?

Comment: @CGR it's hard to customize stuff like ProgressView that are from the system. It might be easier to just [make your own progress bar](https://www.simpleswiftguide.com/how-to-build-linear-progress-bar-in-swiftui/).

Comment: It doesn't work for me on macOS Ventura and swift 5.2.

Answer (score 17):

I needed something with a more rounded radius and without concealing the ProgressView inside another View so here's my take on it (extending @aheze 's answer by using the scale effect)

```
struct MyProgressViewStyle: ProgressViewStyle {
  var myColor: Color

  func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
      ProgressView(configuration)
          .accentColor(myColor)
          .frame(height: 8.0) // Manipulate height, y scale effect and corner radius to achieve your needed results
          .scaleEffect(x: 1, y: 2, anchor: .center)
          .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 6))
          .padding(.horizontal)
  }
}
// Here's how to use it inside a View
ProgressView(value: currentProgress, total: totalProgress)
            .progressViewStyle(MyProgressViewStyle(myColor: Color.green))
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. You can customize ProgressView with a ProgressViewStyle. The accepted answer is a hack.